# iOS 10 double click home to pay issue iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone

I find that it is virtually impossible to double click from the lock screen to open wallet and make a payment using a iPhone 6s and iOS 10.

If can remember to shift my thumb and use the edge of the thumbnail to double click the home button then all is good.  On the other hand, I find myself fumbling on paying  at a checkout, unlocking and relocking several times.

The problem appears to be that with iOS 10 as soon as your thumb hits the home button the phone gets unlocked.  Yet double clicking home to open wallet must be done from the locked state.

Is there a better way to deal with opening wallet while standing in a checkout line?  Or do I need to teach myself in that case to double click with my thumbnail instead of thumb print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact question and asked a guy at the Apple store the other day. He mentioned two things:

1. Use a finger you don't have registered to unlock your phone. For example, I have only my thumb and index finger on each hand registered. If I use my middle finger, it won't unlock because it doesn't recognize my fingerprint and give me the time to press it twice. This doesn't work if you have all of your fingers registered, though.
2. If you're using Apple Pay, you don't even need to open up your wallet. If your phone gets within range of an Apple Pay device, the wallet will automatically appear (which was news to me).

Comment: Thanks, #2 is interesting.. I didn't know that and look forward to trying it.   As for #1, I only have my two thumbs enrolled, no fingers.  I don't ever seem to use a finger on the home button tho.  The only workaround I've found so far is to roll my thumb sidewaise and use the corner of my thumbnail to double click for wallet.

Comment: I didn't believe #2 either but the guy had an Apple Pay demo and tried it and it worked like a charm. Super neat. Unfortunately I don't think there's a "best of both worlds" solution.

Comment: #2 is a fact.  It removes the need to double click before payment.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the behaviour of the Home button in iOS 10, although this *may* reduce the way you'd like to use the new lock screen features in iOS 10.

To change the Home button behaviour, follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings > General > Accessibility
2. Scroll to and tap the Home Button setting
3. Change the Click Speed and/or Rest Finger to Open settings

Test the changes out and see if it works for you.

Comment: With Default click speed & Rest Finger to Open switched off, I can easily get to ApplePay, even with Raise to Wake active. Takes a while to get used to, but now I'm getting the hang of it, it's far better than the iOS9 way, where you'd have to avoid using an authorised finger or the darn thing would be on the springboard before you'd even thought about it.

Comment: I've now played with the settings for the home button as mentioned in this answer.  As far as double clicking the locked phone for wallet, the double click sped doesn't seem to be the issue, the speed of the thumbprint scanner unlocking the phone is the problem.